# what information does /proc/slabinfo give?

Tags: android, linux, memory, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

An application is cosuming memory. Seen as "memory used" in top. I would like to know if its corresponding driver is allocating memory and not releasing it when the application exits. Will /proc/slabinfo help me find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/slabinfo` gives information about memory usage on the slab level. Linux kernels uses slab pools to manage memory above the page level. Commonly used objects have their own slab pools.

http://unixfoo.blogspot.co.il/2008/11/what-is-procslabinfo.html